# AwesomeVM how to remove the titlebar from termite?

Tags: linux, awesome-wm

As the question states how do I go about removing the title bar from the termite terminal? I have gone through the config files in termite but can't seem to find anything.

Picture included:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMGXv.jpg

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.\

Answer (score 2):

```
 { rule_any = {type = { "normal", "dialog" }
 }, properties = { titlebars_enabled = true }
 },
```

change to

```
 { rule_any = {type = { "normal", "dialog" }
 }, properties = { titlebars_enabled = false }
 },
```

in the rc.lua line 492.

Comment: The line number depends on the version of `awesome`. Different versions have different default configs have different line numbers.